# Swift - 'Bool' is not a subtype of 'Void'?

Tags: swift

I'm getting the following error: 'Bool' is not a subtype of 'Void'

performBlock takes a void closure with no argument, and method itself has a single argument, so I should be able to use the following syntax for my closure. Why am i getting this compile error?

```
workingManagedObjectContext.performBlock {
    self.workingManagedObjectContext.save(nil)

    self.managedObjectContext.performBlock {
       self.managedObjectContext.save(nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The argument to `performBlock` is a closure taking no arguments and returning Void
(i.e. no return value).
If the closure consists of a **single expression**, the return type is inferred from
the type of that expression. The type of

```
self.managedObjectContext.save(nil)
```

is `Bool`, which cannot implicitly be converted to `Void`.
To fix that problem, you can add an explicit return statement:

```
self.managedObjectContext.performBlock {
    self.managedObjectContext.save(nil)
    return
}
```

or (better), check the return value of the `save` operation instead of ignoring it:

```
self.managedObjectContext.performBlock {
    var error : NSError?
    if !self.managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
        // report error
    }
}
```

(and do the same for the outer level save).

---

**Update:** As of Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3), unannotated single-expression closures with non-Void return types can now be used in Void contexts. So this does now compile without errors:

```
self.managedObjectContext.performBlock {
    self.managedObjectContext.save(nil)
    // explicit "return" not needed anymore in Swift 1.2
}
```

(Of course it is still better to actually *check* the return value
from the save operation.)