# 'Cannot convert the expression's type' with optional in closure body

Tags: swift, closures, option-type

I have come across (most definitely) a feature that I don't quite understand. I have a closure, that takes in a `Float` and has no return value, aka `(number: Float) -> Void`. In that closure, I perform a call on optional value, not forcing its unwrapping, because I like the behavior since the optional is a delegate (= if it's nil, don't do anything).

But when I do that, I get an error:
`Cannot convert the expression's type '...' to type Float.`

Interestingly enough, when I simply add `println()`, the error disappears. I have simplified my case to tiny little example for illustration:

```
var optional: [String : Int]?
let closure: (number: Int) -> Void = { (number) -> Void in
    optional?.updateValue(number, forKey: "key")
    //println() <-- when this gets uncommented, error disappears
}
```

My bet would be that the compiler maybe doesn't like that in some cases I'm not handling the float number, but since I am not returning the value then it should just disappear right? What am I missing?

Comment: Try adding a "return" to the end of the function.  Sometimes the compiler gets confused about closure return types. Wouldn't think its an issue here since you're explicitly setting it, but...

Comment: Interesting, that did silence it. One would hope it wouldn't be necessary since the syntax is meant to be as short as possible. But I guess it could be just because it's still very young.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598711/swift-bool-is-not-a-subtype-of-void/25598943#25598943 . not the same error but the same reason.

Comment: It's interesting though, that even when I specify, that the method I call on my optional delegate object is returning Void, it confuses the compiler. Then again, return solves the problem and it seems like the issue has been addressed in Swift 1.2. Thanks for the insight :-)

Comment: Optional Chaining always returns `Optional`. If the final result is `Void`, it returns `Optional<Void>`. Moreover `updateValue()` in `Dictionary` returns `Value?` type. In your case, `optional?.updateValue(number, forKey: "key")` is `Int?`.

Comment: Well, a more complete explanation is that a closure with a single expression is assumed to return the result of that expression.  In this case, the return type of the expression is `Int?` so you have mixed information, does it return `Void`, or `Int?`  An explicit return clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression containing a single expression is inferred to return that result, hence:

```
let closure: (number: Int) -> Void = { (number) -> Void in
    optional?.updateValue(number, forKey: "key")
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
let closure: (number: Int) -> Void = { (number) -> Void in
    return optional?.updateValue(number, forKey: "key")
}
```

You now have conflicting return types between `Void` and `Int?` (remember, `updateValue` returns the old value)

Splitting it up with an explicit return clarifies the inferred typing.

```
let closure: (number: Int) -> Void = { (number) -> Void in
    optional?.updateValue(number, forKey: "key")
    return
}
```

Comment: Yes that would completely make sense. I am really sorry my "simplified" example confused the readers by picking a method that actually does return a value. The thing is, that the *real* method I call in my code on the optional in fact **is** returning Void. That's what made me confused in the very beginning. The code is `self.delegate?.onUploadProgress(progress)` and the type of `onUploadProgress` is `(Float) -> Void`. No `Int?` like with `updateValue`...

Comment: And when I put `return self.delegate?.onUploadProgress(progress)`, the compiler suggests to add `!` at the end of the expression. And when I do it, it suggests removing it. *"There is something rotten in the state of Denmark"*...

Comment: Again, at that point you have clashing return types since the declared return type is Void.

Comment: How is that possible? The closure has return type `Void` and so does `onUploadProgress(...)` - I don't see conflicting return types?

Comment: Since you're using optional unwrapping, the expression returns `Void?`. Any expression containing optional unwrapping returns an optional.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't know Void could be optional too. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think your closure won't like returning nil because Void can't be converted to nil.

If you do that in a playground:

```
var n: Void = ()
n = nil
```

You'll get this error:
error: type 'Void' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

Comment: I am sorry I can't see the connection with my question. I am not trying to convert anything to nil. On the contrary - I am not returning anything.