# Calling Swift Closure Inside Closure

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
  twitterAPI?.verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock({ (userName, password) -> Void in


            twitterAPI?.getUserTimelineWithScreenName(userName, count: 100, successBlock: { ([AnyObject]!) -> Void in



                }, errorBlock: { (error :NSError!) -> Void in

            })



            }, errorBlock: { (error :NSError!) -> Void in

                println("error block")
        })
```

I am getting the following errors:

[image]

I tried saying self inside the outer closure but it did not work. What am I missing?

UPDATED: Still having build errors:

[image]

UPDATE: If I put the getUserTimeline method outside the closure then it works. THIS ONE WORKS.

```
//        twitterAPI?.getUserTimelineWithScreenName("", successBlock: { (objects :[AnyObject]!) -> Void in
//            
//            }, errorBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
//        
//        })
```

But this DOES NOT:

```
twitterAPI?.verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock({ (userName, password) -> Void in


    self.twitterAPI?.getUserTimelineWithScreenName("", successBlock: { (objects :[AnyObject]!) -> Void in

        }, errorBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in

    })



    }, errorBlock: { (error :NSError!) -> Void in


})
```

UPDATE: Definition of getUserTimeLine method

```
self.twitterAPI?.getUserTimelineWithScreenName(<#screenName: String!#>, successBlock: <#(([AnyObject]!) -> Void)!##([AnyObject]!) -> Void#>, errorBlock: <#((NSError!) -> Void)!##(NSError!) -> Void#>)
```

[image]

UPDATE: Now, I am getting a build error saying missing argument sinceID. I am not even using that constructor.

```
 if let twitterAPI = self.twitterAPI {

            twitterAPI.verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock({ (userName, password) -> Void in

                twitterAPI.getUserTimelineWithScreenName(userName, successBlock: { (objects :[AnyObject]!) -> Void in

                    }, errorBlock: { (error :NSError!) -> Void in

                })


                }, errorBlock: { (error :NSError!) -> Void in

            })

        }
```

Comment: Use `self.twitterAPI?.getUserTimeline.......`

Comment: I am still having issues! Please check the updated screenshot.

Comment: The problem comes only inside the closure when referencing using self. If I place the getUserTime.. method outside the parent closure then it works.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock`?

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code above to give better idea of what works and what does not work.

Comment: Can you update the question to show how the function `getUserTimelineWithScreenName` is defined? The error implies that you are passing the wrong type or number of arguments to that function.

Comment: Just updated the question with definition as well as screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74663/discussion-between-john-doe-and-danielbeard).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
        twitterAPI?.verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock({ (userName, password) -> Void in
            self.twitterAPI?.getUserTimelineWithScreenName(userName, successBlock: { (objects :[AnyObject]!) -> Void in

                }, errorBlock: { (error :NSError!) -> Void in
            })

            return  // <-- ADDED

            }, errorBlock: { (error :NSError!) -> Void in
        })
```

In this case

```
{ (userName, password) -> Void in
    self.twitterAPI?.getUserTimelineWithScreenName("", successBlock: { (objects :[AnyObject]!) -> Void in
    }, errorBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
    })
}
```

is a "single expression closure" that has implicit non `Void` return.

As of Xcode 6.2 / Swift 1.1, you need explicit `return` here.

Or, use Xcode 6.3 / Swift 1.2 that has fixed this problem.

See this question: [One-line closure without return type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24150400/3804019) or [Swift - 'Bool' is not a subtype of 'Void'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25598711/3804019)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, by the method names you are using, I'm guessing you are using the [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) library. If that's the case, you'll want something like this:

```
    if let twitterAPI = self.twitterAPI {
        twitterAPI.verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock({ (String) -> Void in
            twitterAPI.getUserTimelineWithScreenName("test", successBlock: { (objects: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in
                println("success")
                }, errorBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    println("failure")
            })
            }, errorBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in

        })
    }
```

Note the let call before using the optional `self.twitterAPI` variable.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code like yours but now getting an error related to sinceID. But I am not even using that constructor. Updated the code in the original question.

Comment: Yes, I am using STTwitter library. I copy pasted your code and got the following error "Missing argument for parameter sinceID in call".

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 4

Here is the simple example.
But better to make an implementation through **monad**.

```
...
guard let api = twitterAPI else { return }

api.verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock({ userName, password in
    api.getUserTimelineWithScreenName(
        userName, 
        count: 100, 
        successBlock: { value in
            // success
        }) { error in 
            print("get user error: \(error)") 
        }
}) { error in 
    print("verify error: \(error)") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really misleading error message. The problem is that the inner variable  can't be of optional type so you need to `if/let` it.

Check this out in a playground...

```
class Foo:NSObject {
    func doThing(bug:Int,completion:((Void)->(Void))) {

    }
}

let woot = Foo()
var bar:Foo? = Foo()

bar?.doThing(7, completion: {});

woot.doThing(3, completion: {

     bar?.doThing(4, completion:{});

});
```

It doesnt compile and the message

> Cannot convert the expression type '(IntegerLiteralConvertible,
>   completion:()->()-$T3)' to type '()'

Isn't exactly illuminating to the problem.

So you unwrap the optional

```
woot.doThing(3, completion: {

    if let bar = bar {
        bar.doThing(4, completion:{});
    }

});
```

And it now compiles.

And to the other issue

If you check the `STTwitterAPI.h` header

```
- (NSObject<STTwitterRequestProtocol> *)getUserTimelineWithScreenName:(NSString *)screenName
                                                         successBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *statuses))successBlock
                                                           errorBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;
```

is just a convenience for the full signature of this.

```
- (NSObject<STTwitterRequestProtocol> *)getUserTimelineWithScreenName:(NSString *)screenName
                                                              sinceID:(NSString *)sinceID
                                                                maxID:(NSString *)maxID
                                                                count:(NSUInteger)count
                                                         successBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *statuses))successBlock
                                                           errorBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;
```

Obj-C to Swift bridging places everything after the the first selector chunk inside the brackets so convenience methods tend to confuse things by code completing but not providing the canonical case.

So in your case (without me having `STTwitter`) this is what you want.

```
twitterAPI?.verifyCredentialsWithUserSuccessBlock({ (userName, password) -> Void in

    if let twitterAPI = self.twitterAPI {
       twitterAPI.getUserTimelineWithScreenName("JohnSmith",sinceID:someID,maxID:anotherID,count:1000, successBlock: { (objects)[AnyObject]!) -> Void in

        }, errorBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in

       })
   }


    }, errorBlock: { (error :NSError!) -> Void in


})
```

how you choose to populate `sinceID` , `maxID` and `count` is up to you . I've never used the API so won't guess. They might be nil'able